# DataProxy vs DataPreview

Tags: ckan

I have CKAN 2.8 set up and am planning to use it as a portal for serving files for users on a local network. Many of the resources are uploaded to the CKAN server, which is not accessible from the internet. I want the Data Explorer preview to work and am wondering the best approach. I have a few plugins installed, and one which may be a factor is [ckanext-resourceauthorizer](https://github.com/etri-odp/ckanext-resourceauthorizer).

I see two incomplete solutions, but am open to others as well

1. Since the server is not accessible via the internet the regular DataProxy would not work. I updated found a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/unocha/hdx-dataproxy) and was able to install a local instance and point the recline.js dataproxy_url to it. This works for my public datasets, but private ones get a 404 error and no preview.
2. I see [ckanext-datapreview](https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-datapreview) performs similar functionality, but the notes state that recline needs to be modified to use the extension. It appears this modification is more than altering the url, but have been unable to find more information.

I am looking for a recommendation on the best path forward:

Can either of these options provide the previews I am looking for?

DataProxy is supposedly deprecated is that a reason to avoid it?

Is there a standalone patched recline to interface with ckanext-datapreview?

Comment: Not sure I'm following your question correctly but if you want visuals (data explorer) without relying on dataproxy you can setup datastore and datapusher. Then the visuals data will pull locally from the datastore DB instead of trying to use a service to read the data files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way for CKAN sites to show data previews is with **DataStore** and either DataPusher or [XLoader](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-xloader). When a dataset is present in Datastore, then the package (metadata) should have the `datastore_enabled` flag set to true and recline will simply get the data from Datastore (postgres), in preference to DataProxy service. To get the data into Datastore when ever a dataset is added to CKAN, then you can setup DataPusher or [XLoader](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-xloader).

The **DataProxy** is the default when you install CKAN, but is not a great solution. It runs in only a little free/cheap AppEngine web service, shared by all CKANs worldwide that haven't been configured to use something better. As you've found, because it's external to CKAN and doesn't hold any credentials for your CKAN, it can't access private datasets or local data. It's not very good at parsing CSV that is out of the ordinary. It's long been [deprecated](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/data-viewer.html#data-explorer) because it's not very good.

[ckanext-preview](https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-datapreview) held a lot of promise, but is sadly no longer maintained - feel free to give it some love. It's an efficient and robust way of parsing CSVs into JSON on the fly i.e. without having to hold it in DataStore or other database. I can't quite remember what little change is needed to recline for them to talk, but this could be it: https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-dgu/commit/053e3df96b51cb775c092430bc435939a8c6f492